# Merge branch xyz to master, and also update xyz with merge result

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit, git-extensions

I have branch `master` and `xyz`. I switched to master, then I merged `xyz` to it. But I need same result `master+xyz` in `xyz`. What to do?

Comment: How about switching to xyz and merging master?

Comment: Is it the only solution?

Comment: Do you have any problems with it? Assuming that master does not have any other changes I'd assume both are equal after first merge.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk the master branch contains a merge commit, so the branches are not the same

Comment: Why would you want to have the same result in xyz? As Tomasz said, you can use merge and the xyz branch will be fast forwarded to master.

Comment: Because I forgot to add one fix to xyz branch. Now when I add this fix at master branch, it will be bad looking in history(?)

Comment: I think better cherry pick fix commit.